# Array not rendered React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, rendering

I have the following ToDo component which is called from the App component. I see that the items array is being updated properly from the console logs when the Add Item button is clicked but the contents of the items are not displayed below the button.

```
function ToDo(){
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    const [currItem, setCurrItem] = useState('')

    const handleClick = () => {
        if(!currItem) return
        console.log(currItem)
        let temp = items
        temp.push(currItem)
        setItems([...temp])
        console.log(items)
    }
    return(
        <div>
        <input type='text' onChange={(e) => setCurrItem(e.target.value)}/> 
        <br/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Item</button>
        <br/>
        <div> 
            {
                items.forEach(i => {
                 <div>{i}</div>   
                })
            }
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try switching to `items.map()` instead of `items.forEach()` as `forEach` will not return anything while `map` returns a new array of the `div` elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: Tried .map() as well, still, the array items are not rendered.

Comment: You also need to add a `return` statement to return the `div` element you created, like so: `items.map((i) => { return <div>{i}</div>; })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Comment: and [forEach over es6 Map in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590621/foreach-over-es6-map-in-jsx)

Comment: Thanks @pilchard, makes a lotta sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello  try  to change your code  by  adding this

```
  {items.map((v,i) => {
              return <div key={v}>{i}</div>;
            })}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your `handleClick` function try this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function ToDo() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [currItem, setCurrItem] = useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!currItem) return;
    console.log(currItem);
    let temp = [...items];
    temp.push(currItem);
    setItems(temp);
    console.log(items);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setCurrItem(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Item</button>
      <br />
      <div>
        {items.map((i) => {
          return <div>{i}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDo;
```